# Python - Выбор ответа пользователя, да, нет, ответ некорректный

Tags: python, инспекция-кода

Всем доброго дня! Столкнулся с неочевидной (для меня) проблемой работы цикла.
Программа после своей первой итерации спрашивает пользователя, играем еще раз или нет.
Возможные ответы "д" и "н", если же пользователь ввел другой символ, запрос еще раз. При первом выборе все ок, и "д" и "н" отрабатывают.
Но если выбрать сначала "д", пройти еще одну работу программы, и после выбрать "н", то программа просит ввести "н" еще несколько раз... Загадка

```
from random import *
answers = ["Да", "Нет"]

def new_game():
    flag = True
    while True:
        request = input('Хотите сыграть еще раз? "д" - да, "н" - нет: ')
        if request == "н":
            print('Пока-пока!')
            break
        elif request == "д":
            magicball()
        else:
            print('Не понял вашего ответа')

def magicball():
    while True:
        question = input(f"Задай же свой вопрос: ")
        answer = choice(answers)
        print(f"Мой ответ тебе: {answer}!")
        new_game()
        break
magicball()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема в том, что вы вызываете ещё одну функцию `magicball()`, при этом ту, которую запускаете изначально - не завершаете, поэтому после выбора варианта "нет" условие выхода не срабатывает и она продолжает работать по `while True:`

Если отталкиваться конкретно от вашего кода, то самый простой вариант исправления:

```
elif request == "д":
    magicball()
    break
```

Comment: Спасибо! То , что нужно)

Comment: А если отталкиваться не от моего (не самого лучшего кода)), есть какой-то общепринятый алгоритм простого диалога - да, нет, введите еще раз?

Comment: @СергейНовожилов совсем общепринятого нет, но более лаконично выглядело бы как-то так: `next_decision = input(...), while next_decision != 'н' : ...`

Answer (score 0):

ошибка была из за цикла while True, он тут не нужен

```
from random import *
answers = ["Да", "Нет"]

def new_game():
    flag = True
    request = input('Хотите сыграть еще раз? "д" - да, "н" - нет: ')
    if request == "н":
        print('Пока-пока!')
    elif request == "д":
        magicball()
    else:
        print('Не понял вашего ответа, попробуйте ввести еще раз')
        new_game()
def magicball():
    question = input(f"Задай же свой вопрос: ")
    answer = choice(answers)
    print(f"Мой ответ тебе: {answer}!")
    new_game()
magicball()
```

Comment: Это нарушит исходную логику человека, который писал программу. Он хотел, чтобы если пользователь введёт что-то отличное от "д" и "н", то программа продолжила его спрашивать, а в вашем варианте - программа завершится

Comment: Спасибо! Как вариант, но тогда не отработает повторный запрос, при вводе чего-то отличного от "д" или "н".

Comment: @Сергей исправил ответ, по идеи так тоже нормально но если хочете с циклом то лучше следуйте первому ответу (Павела)